# How to concatenate the arguments and store it in a variable in unix?

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have two inputs for my program which will be in below format:

```
Jan 22 01:08:20  Sep 15 09:07:10
```

Here the argument `$1 is 22 $2 is 01:08:20 $3 is Sep $4 is 15 $5 09:07:10.` Is it possible to concatenate the arguments and store it in a variable? Such that

```
variable1=Jan 22 01:08:20 and variable2=Sep 15 09:07:10
```

Please help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: `variable1="$1 $2 $3"` `variable2="$4 $5 $6"` ?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.